# Access import into SQL server not importing first line

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, import

I am using a function to import data from a access db into SQL server:

```
public string importDataFromAccess(string table, string fileName)
    { 
        OleDbConnection OleDbConn = new OleDbConnection(String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}", fileName));
        try
        {
            string sSQLTable = table;
            string myExcelDataQuery = "Select * from " + sSQLTable;
            string sSqlConnectionString = connStr;
            string sClearSQL = "DELETE FROM " + sSQLTable;
            SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(sSqlConnectionString);
            SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sClearSQL, SqlConn);
            SqlConn.Open();
            SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlConn.Close();

            OleDbCommand OleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand(myExcelDataQuery, OleDbConn);
            OleDbConn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader dr = OleDbCmd.ExecuteReader();
            SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sSqlConnectionString);
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = sSQLTable;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
            }
            OleDbConn.Close();
            return "Done";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OleDbConn.Close();
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I noticed it isnt importing the first record of each table, can anyone help notice why and how to fix? Hopefully it is only the first row...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need the

```
while (dr.Read())
{
     bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
}
```

And you just need to replace that with

```
     bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
```

The [WriteToServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/434atets.aspx) method

> Copies all rows in the supplied IDataReader to a destination table
>   specified by the DestinationTableName property of the SqlBulkCopy
>   object.

But the [dr.Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.read.aspx) that you have called has read the first line out of the Reader and advanced the IDataReader to the next record (so it is not accessible to the WriteServer method).